# Работа с Git и человеком, который им не пользуется

Tags: git

Добрый день!

Ситуация такая: есть проект, который лежит на удаленном сервере, я все изменения вношу на локальной машине, потом при помощи Git отправляю изменения на сервер, есть дизайнер, который не умеет работать с Git и вносит правки на продакшене.
Мне приходится лезть на сервер добавлять все правки дизайнера в репозиторий, а потом пулить (pull) изменения в свою локальную версию проекта.

Хочется перестать сливать изменения дизайнера на продакшене, а делать это на своей локальной машине, а потом все одим махом отправлять на удаленный сервер.

Есть ли в Git какой-нибудь инструмент, с помощью которого можно пулить незафиксированные изменения?
Может быть, есть какой другой способ работы в команде в такой ситуации?

Заранее спасибо за Ваш ответ/совет.

P.S.

*Ответ капитана*: Научить дизайнера использовать Git.

Comment: А вариант с тем, чтобы дать дизайнеру скрипт (или батник), который все сделает за него и без понимания работы GIT, не подходит?

Comment: Если есть возможность отобрать доступ к продакшн, то указать дизайнеру на веб-интерфейс репозитория на githab или свой типа gitlab, с помощью которого он может правки в онлайн-редакторе вносить и по желанию прикрутить веб-хук на коммит, чтобы публиковать правки автоматически.

Альтернативно, можно научить несколько команд в GUI выполнять (pull, add, commit, push).

Пытаться с помощью `git diff`, `inotifywait` отлавливать локальные изменения -- не продуктивно. Это не здоровая рабочая обстановка, если человек, который может сломать систему не берёт на себя никакой ответственности за починку.

Comment: Зачем дизу гит? Создайте папку /psd добавьте её в гит игнор и работайте с дизайнером через ftp, ssh

Comment: @Олег Б извините не учтонил, под дизайнером я подразумеваю не только создателя .psd шаблонов, а еще верстальщика

Comment: @Alex Krass можно поподробнее про "скрипт (или батник)" а то с администрированием у меня слабовато

Comment: @zsiteru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: `sudo install git-to-designer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если он ещё и верстальщик (а может, и фронтенд разработчик), то без гита тяжело, настройте ему `.ssh` ключ чтобы не требовалось вводить никаких паролей и научите такой команде: `git add . && git commit -am 'frontend development' && git pull origin master && git push origin master` - объясните что это будет что-то типа "сохранить свои изменения и вылить". В консоле гита ему достаточно будет набрать "вверх" и "enter" и всё. :)

Если про "батник", то смысл в следующем:

- найти папку, куда установлен гит, у меня это `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`;
- элемент списка;
- добавить "переменную среду" (PATH): `Панель управления > Система > Дополнительные параметры > Переменные среды >`;
- выбираем параметр `PATH` и дописываем через `;` этот пусть к гиту;
- создаем файл, например, `apply.bat`, и прописываем там:

  git add . && git commit -am 'frontend development' && git pull origin master && git push origin master

Не забудьте поменять ветку на свою.